# Can developers control their private keys?

Tags: coinbase-api

I need to create a mobile wallet app in which private keys are only stored on the user's device.

Can I do this with the Coinbase Wallet API?  i.e. does the Coinbase Wallet API store/manage the private keys on a server?

Thanks,
  ~Johnny

Comment: kindly share if you have gone to another direction in order to create your own wallet.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Jhonny You can not create a Wallet using Coinbase Api.
Instead You can use their services into your own Application. 
Actually I am looking for the same thing and have research for few days and concluded to use it.